# How to add new job or update the trigger for existing job in the Quartz.Net?

Tags: c#, cron, quartz.net

I am getting job details like start time  and effective date from the database and on the basis of the job details, I am creating the job but what if I have got another entry for new job or the start time has been changed for the scheduled job, so how new job will be added in the job scheduler or new start time will be changed in the scheduler.

I am using C#.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to schedule the job with a new trigger. Triggers can't be updated once they're created.

Comment: Hi,

I am quite new to quartz.net so can you please provide me some sample application. I will appreciate your efforts.

Thanks

Comment: Which version are you running? The API has changed significantly between V1 and V2.

Comment: Actually they can after 2.1.x

Answer (score 12):

I do not know if it was not possible to update the existing trigger in Quartz in the previous version, but it is possible to update the trigger in the newer version (as of 2.* ).

The update could be achieved as follows (adapted for Quartz.net);

```
// retrieve the trigger
Trigger oldTrigger = sched.GetTrigger(new TriggerKey("oldTrigger", "group1"));

// obtain a builder that would produce the trigger
TriggerBuilder tb = oldTrigger.GetTriggerBuilder();

// update the schedule associated with the builder, and build the new trigger
// (other builder methods could be called, to change the trigger in any desired way)
Trigger newTrigger = tb.WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(10).WithRepeatCount(10))
    .Build();

sched.RescheduleJob(oldTrigger, newTrigger);
```

[Source](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/cookbook/UpdateTrigger.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can delete and create new one trigger. As already answered here.

Using Quarzt 1.0.3 to delete trigger use

```
Scheduler.UnscheduleJob(triggerName, groupName);
```

and to create new one for example

```
CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger(string.Format(TRIGGER_NAME_FORMAT, jobName), TRIGGER_DEFAULT_GROUP, jobName, groupName, utcDate, null, cronExpression, TimeZoneInfo.Utc); 

Scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

The other option that I did not check is to update cron expression
if your trigger is defined as CronTrigger

But I never checked it so I do not know for sure if it will work.

```
foreach (Trigger trigger in Scheduler.GetTriggersOfJob(jobName, group))
{

    if (trigger is CronTrigger)
    {

        CronTrigger cronTrigger = trigger as CronTrigger;
        if (cronTrigger != null)
        {
            cronTrigger.CronExpressionString = "Your Updated Cron Strin";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, triggers cannot be updated once they are created.